# Django mail sending error with DEBUG=False

Tags: django, email

In my Django website I have a contact form. If the contact form is submitted there need to be send an email to user and admin. When **DEBUG** is True the email was sent. But when **DEBUG** is False it won't send mail. Here I am using **Django mail**.

`settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abc123'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: Please post the relevant mail settings from the `settings.py` file.

Comment: So, one silly question - have you enabled less secure apps on your account? https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps or have you set app specific passwords?

Comment: And how is the code where you actually send the email looks like? could you add `fail_silently=False` attribute to it as well?

Comment: Yes, I enabled less secure apps on my account and `fail_silently=False`. But still got error

Answer (score -2):

First, when DEBUG is True the email was sent, is the email was sent by SMTP server or it just print the email in the console? Are you also using the SMTP emailbackend for your EMAIL_BACKEND settings or you are using the console.backend for your development settings? Because usually you should set your Email_backend to console.backend when you are in development mood.
Second, when you switch to production mood, the application won't send mail, Did you get any errors? And did you test the google smtp server connection works?(check this for detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#smtp-backend) Sometimes you have to set the ssl_certfile and ssl_keyfile for the google smtp server depends on your google smtp security level.

Comment: My `settings.py` is same as shown above. If `DEBUG=True` then mail was send from `EMAIL_HOST_USER` to given recipient email.`EMAIL_HOST_USER` is a gmail account.But when `DEBUG=False` it won`t send email.