# Sending Emails in Production Environment

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean, email

I have a web app I'm hosting on Digital ocean using nginx and gunicorn.  I recently tried to add password reset capabilities for my users as well as a contact form.  When I ran and tested on my local machine everything worked fine, but now that I've moved to production I get a 500 error when I try to send a password reset email, and my contact form is not generating any email message.

Is there some additional set up related to digital ocean, or nginx that needs to be done to allow emails to be sent?

my settings.py is set up as follows:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@programaticlearning.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'CorrectPassword'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: The 500 you're getting is giveaway there's something wrong. Do you have any logs related to that? Can you add it here? If not, easiest way (but not the recommended way) is to enable `settings.DEBUG` for a moment, trigger the error again and check the traceback on Django debug page.

Comment: So when I change DEBUG = True it starts working.  So whatever is happening is happening due to DEBUG being turned on.  And I've checked the logs there's nothing helpful there

Comment: Is this the only thing which does not work? I once had problem which went away with switching `DEBUG`, and the problem was I had a wrong value `settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Comment: Hmmm Maybe it is allowed hosts....  It looks to be an issue that's come up before:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093584/django-mail-sending-error-with-debug-false

Comment: Ok, hard to tell without the traceback. Setup some kind of logging to get hand on the traceback. Either manually into a logfile or something like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

I needed to create the Site with the correct domain in order for Django's Authentication views to work properly.  I was using a different database in production and hadn't yet created the proper domain in the Site table.